# How to edit selectize input after calling selectize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

My goal is to reset selected values in selectize input. I called selectize function in seperate js file (working with Ruby on Rails), so there is no option to create some global selectize input variable (at least I want to avoid it).

In select2 I would solve similar issue like that:

```
$(".select2").select2("val", "")
```

but when I call `selectize()` second time on the input all previous options and collection loaded via ajax just dissappear.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selectize uses `.selectized` as its identifying class.

Unfortunately, selectize is not accessible via `$('.selectized').selectize` - you need to go directly to the `<select>`/`<input>` element - `$('.selectized')[0].selectize` as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md).

I don't believe you can access all selectize items at once, you need to iterate through them. I recommend using the [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function, such as something like:

```
$.map($('.selectized'), function(item, index) { 
  item.selectize.setValue('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works but in my case I had to call it with selectize()[0] `$('.selectized').first().selectize()[0].selectize.setValue('')`